# Combine two Servant Servers

Tags: haskell, servant

According to Servant's manual https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial/Server.html a very simple Server can be created that way:

```
type UserAPI1 = "users" :> Get '[JSON] [User]

server1 :: Server UserAPI1
server1 = return users1

userAPI :: Proxy UserAPI1
userAPI = Proxy
```

I noticed, that I it doable to keep API parts separated and combine them together later on, e.g.

```
type ClientAPI = 
    "users" :> Get '[HTML] (Html ()) 

type ServerAPI = 
    "users" :> Get '[JSON] [User] 
-- works fine
type API = ("api" :> ServerAPI) :<|> ClientAPI
```

Can I do the same with Server values ? I can't find an easy way to join two "servers" together:

```
clientAPI :: Server ClientAPI
clientAPI = usersView 

serverAPI :: Server ServerAPI
serverAPI = fetchUsers

api :: Server API
-- doesn't work - is there a way to combine two servers together ?
api = clientAPI + serverAPI
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `(:<|>)` combinator that you use to combine your different API routes at the type level also works at the value level for combining handlers.

See the [Hackage docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.16.2/docs/Servant-API.html#v::-60--124--62-) and [Servant tutorial](https://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Server.html#more-endpoints)

So simply replace the `+` in your `api` with `:<|>` and you should be good to go.

EDIT: Except that order matters. The handlers in the value representing your server must be in the same order as the different routes in the type-level API declaration. So it should work if you define `api = serverAPI :<|> clientAPI`.

Comment: Are you sure this works for Server as well ? I tried using :<|> there instead of + in my example and I get a type error.

Comment: ah, on closer inspection of your example, you have the `clientAPI` and `serverAPI` in the wrong order. They must be in the same order in your server declaration as in your type-level API declaration.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks - I'll give it a go after work, at home :).

Comment: OK, it works. Thank you. 
And sorry - turned out to be such an easy thing. I'm relatively new to Haskell, almost every solution to common problems I find keep on turning my brain inside out and I assumed this problem is non-trivial as well.

Comment: No need to apologise at all, I'm also relatively new to Haskell (at least for "real" use rather than basic exercises) and can totally sympathise with that point of view!

Comment: @RobinZigmond I believe the combinator should be (:<|>)

Comment: @lsund thanks! I've actually not used Servant (or Haskell much in general...) in several years but it appears you're correct. Not sure how this went un-noticed in over 3 years! Now edited.

Comment: Funnily enough, in my code I used the right operator. Thanks for noticing anyway @Isund so that now everyone reading this thread is saved from needless pain and tears.